# having trouble writing a dataframe to an sqlite database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-requests, statistics

sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.

Here is the exact code to reproduce the error

go to this page with dev tools open

https://stats.nba.com/teams/boxscores-traditional/

on teamgamelogs endpoint right click -> Copy -> copy as curl(bash)

convert to python requests
https://curl.trillworks.com/

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import sqlite3

response = requests.get('https://stats.nba.com/stats/teamgamelogs?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&VsConference=&VsDivision=', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

conn = sqlite3.connect('nbastats.db')
stats = response.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(stats["resultSets"])


df.to_sql('Team_stats', conn, if_exists='append')
```

I dont understand why I am getting this error.

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get access to the page you have cited. Nonetheless, you need to engineer data before putting it to the SQL from dataframe. Check for data types:

```
 df.dtypes()
```

If there is "object" in the second column, then you need to check whether it is sql supported type.

Comment: this is the response

>>> df.dtypes()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
>>> df
           name                                            headers                                             rowSet
0  TeamGameLogs  [SEASON_YEAR, TEAM_ID, TEAM_ABBREVIATION, TEAM...  [[2019-20, 1610612746, LAC, LA Clippers, 00219...

Answer (score 0):

Check the returned data types from the response. As we know SQLite 3 only supports below data types.

1)NULL. The value is a NULL value.

2)INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

3)REAL. The value is a floating-point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating-point number.

4)TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

5)BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Reference : https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out.

my different way of doing things was to use the .get_data_frames()[0] function provided by the API and then I was able to get a data frame by selecting the 0 position in the list. This was able to be inserted into the database.